# PIP not able to install dependencies

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging

I have built and published a package to pypi using `poetry` build, and have also specified dependencies which it uses inside `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
PyGithub = "1.54.1"
colorama = "0.4.4"
PyInquirer = "1.0.3"
```

However when I install and run this package on a computer without those installed, I get this error

```
ERROR: Could not find version that satisfies the requirement PyGithub==1.54.1 (from <my_package_name_here) (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyGithub==1.54.1 (from <my_package_name_here)
```

How can I make `pip` install those automatically whenever someone installs my package using `pip install package`? Or is it not possible? This looks like it's trying to install them but can't find them?

Comment: What version of python are you using? 1.54.1 is compatible with >= 3.6 of python.

Comment: I'm using 3.9 -> the weirdest thing is that running `pip install PyGithub` installs it correctly, but if trying to install it together with my package it breaks

Comment: I suspect this is a poetry issue and not something with how you configure it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your are using the public [pypi repository index](https://pypi.org/).
If not, probably you're using [test.pypi](https://test.pypi.org/) or another private repository, which does not contains all dependencies you specified.

In that case you can pass an extra repository index.

### Use pip extra-index-url

```sh
pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple PACKAGE==PACKAGE_VERSION
```

By using an extra index, if pip couldn't find a package in the private repository it'll take a look at the official index.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what was wrong - I was testing the package on [test.pypi](http://test.pypi.org), and since I was doing that, it was trying to install the required dependencies from there, and not from the ordinary PyPi. When published to PyPi everything is working.